# can't push to github - fatal: remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github

I just made a commit and pushed it to Github and everything worked fine.  Then I made another change, added, committed and attempted to push.  This time I am getting

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I thought maybe it was the size of the file I just added - 2.6Megs.  So I did

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Still no go.

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

tells me that I'm authenticated.

That's the extent of my git knowledge and it seems to be too generic an error message to yield much from Google.  Any ideas?

Comment: do you have any other remotes available - could you attempt a connection with one and comment with the results, please and ty?

Comment: Ugh.  Disregard.  Rebooting the VM I was working in did the trick. Thanks for your response, Joe.

Comment: so which protocol do you really use to connect ? SSH or HTTPS? those are very different protocols and you should understand which one you use, before trying to track the connection-specific problems

Comment: a great man once said "have you tried turning it off and on again?" - no problem

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a problem with GitHub’s SSH access, so give it a bit time until they fix it. *Edit: It should be fixed now.*

> 16:13 UTC: Investigating SSH access problems on one fileserver pair
>
> 16:26 UTC: Everything operating normally.

[GitHub status](https://status.github.com).